# jquery select an element in a table before another

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an table where i add some rows

```
....
<td><strong class="has-text-success thisState">Connect</strong></td>
<td><a class="is-danger buttonDisconnect"><strong>Disconnect</strong></a></td>
....
```

i need to select .thisState from an click over .buttonDisconnect ....
i try this but didn't work

```
$('#table').on('click', ".buttonDisconnect", function () {
    .... disconnection code
    $(this).html("<strong>Connect</strong>");
    $(this).toggleClass("buttonDisconnect is-danger buttonConnect has-text-success");
    // toggle state
    $(this).prev(".thisState").text("Disconnect");
    $(this).prev(".thisState").toggleClass("has-text-danger has-text-success");
});
```

Comment: $(this).parent().prev().find(".thisState").text("Disconnect");
$(this).parent().prev().find(".thisState").toggleClass("has-text-danger has-text-success"); 
this may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a selector to `.prev`, the previous element will be selected *only* if the previous element matches the selector. But the selector you're passing is for a *child* of the previous element - it doesn't match the previous element.

Another issue is that the clicked element is the `<a>`, not the `<td`> - navigate to the parent `<td>` before going to the previous one.

Navigate to the previous element unconditionally and use `.children` to go to its child filtering by the selector, then do what you need to do:

```
const $prevStrongState = $(this).parent().prev().children('.thisState');
$prevStrongState.text("Disconnect");
$prevStrongState.toggleClass("has-text-danger has-text-success");
```

```js
$('#table').on('click', ".buttonDisconnect", function() {
  $(this).html("<strong>Connect</strong>");
  $(this).toggleClass("buttonDisconnect is-danger buttonConnect has-text-success");
  const $prevStrongState = $(this).parent().prev().children('.thisState');
  $prevStrongState.text("Disconnect");
  $prevStrongState.toggleClass("has-text-danger has-text-success");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><strong class="has-text-success thisState">Connect</strong></td>
    <td><a class="is-danger buttonDisconnect"><strong>Disconnect</strong></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call to `prev` you are getting the previous element of your current element.

Since your element has no previous siblings, this returns nothing. Instead, you have to go up in the DOM to get the previous `td` and then look for the `thisState` children:

```
$(this).closest('td').prev('td').children(".thisState");
```